# 現在ログインしているユーザー名を、ツールバーに表示したい。

Tags: windows

ユーザー名の入ったwindows10の画面をスクリーンキャプチャしたい。

代わりに、
・デスクトップに、ユーザー名のフォルダーを作って表示しています。
・壁紙をつくる。
他に、いい方法があれば教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: キャプチャした画像にユーザー名を書き込めばいいのでは？

Comment: いいですね。画像をエクセルに貼り付けて印刷するので、事前にユーザー名の文字を書き込んだシートを用意する。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はじめまして。運用に利用されるのでしょうか。

SysInternalsにこういったツールがあるので利用が可能です。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo

ユーザーにやってもらうなら、新規ツールバーを作成し。
ユーザーフォルダを指定するのもいいかもしれません。
https://laboradian.com/win-toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

タスクバーで良ければ、タイトルをユーザー名にしたWindowを起動すれば良いのではないでしょうか。
タスクバーが結合されてしまうようなら専用のアプリが必要ですが、「結合しない」であればPowerShellでもいけますね。

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = $env:UserName
$form.ShowDialog()
```